# Ruby on Rails Locking Sqlite Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I want to know if `lock` parameter when passed to the query statement will actually lock the record and avoid concurrent reading.

Ex:
`Query.where(:id => 1, :lock => true)`

Does this guarantee that no one else will read this record till I release the lock?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `locking` applies to `update`, and not `read`. When a record is locked, usually it is possible to view the record; the more important question is whether anyone can update the record when it is locked.

The syntax you have mentioned would look for a field by name `lock` in the table.

For [pessimistic locking with rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking), the syntax is as follows:

```
Query.where(:id => 1 ).lock( true )
```

As explained in the rails guides documentation I linked above:

> Pessimistic locking uses a locking mechanism provided by the underlying database.

So it is recommended to look into the database documentation to see what kind of locking mechanism is provided by that database.

Playing around with locking functionality in multiple `rails console` sessions, I was able to update a record from one window, while the same record was locked from another window.

So it doesn't look like my version of sqlite database doesn't support locking.

Comment: Don't forget locks are released at the end of the current transaction (ie at the end of the statement if there is no explicit transaction). A pessimist lock should prevent further reads